# JavaScript/jQuery trying to make a reset page function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a function which can be called to reset the page into the state before modifications were made. Now the normal JS one worked but it broke my other function which provided answers for the quiz via div population.

I've tried

```
var originalState = $("health").clone();  

$(".reset").click(function() {
 console.log('called');
 console.log(originalState);
$("health").replaceWith(originalState.clone());
 console.log(originalState);
});
```

And with vanilla script

```
var container = document.getElementById("health");
var content = container.innerHTML;

//function reset() {
  //var container = document.getElementById("health");
  //container.innerHTML = html;
  //answers = [];
//}

var html;
window.onload = function() {
  html = document.getElementById("health").innerHTML;
};
```

This gets broken by the JS fix.

```
$(".correctKey").click(function() {
    $(".dropbox").each(function(index) {
        $(this).text(correctAnswers[index]);
        answers = correctAnswers.slice();
    });
});
```

HTML (Not sure if it'll help)

```
<div class="container" id="health">
  <div class="row dropable-area">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="dropbox panel panel-default" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Codepen https://codepen.io/jcollinz/pen/NgywJx, the answer key works if it is pressed before the reset button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close... Close... Just missing concepts.
The "global variable" will stay as long as the page is loaded...
And as long as it isn't changed.

```
var originalState = $("health").clone();   // Global variable holding
                                           // the "onload state" html.

$(".reset").click(function() {
  console.log('Reset called');
  $("health").replaceWith(originalState);  // HERE, originalState is the global variable.
                                           // Not the original element itself.
                                           // No need to re-clone it.

  answers = []:                            // Reset this variable too?
});
```

Then [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), as [Alexander Staroselsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5059657/alexander-staroselsky) correctly mentionned, is needed to access elements "replaced"... Since the DOM "Document Object Model" will not be notifed of these changes, you have to care about how to access those "new" elements after an [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/), [`before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/), [`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/), [`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), etc...

You have to alway "attach" the function, particularly the one which are `event` triggered, to "static" elements, and delegate... Or starting from a "static" element, use `find` or `eq` to target them.

And there is the [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) trick also... For some uses.

```
$("#health").on("click", ".correctKey", function() {    // [event], [target], [function]
  $("#health").find(".dropbox").each(function(index) {  // Always start form a "static" element.
    $(this).text(correctAnswers[index]);

    answers = correctAnswers.slice();                   // I don't know what you do with this variable.
                                                        // But there a possible need to reset too...
  });
});
```

I think the code above should work.
No apparant big changes, as you can see.

But details matter.

---

*«What's not in DOM on load, is dynamic.»*
*«Static can become dynamic»*
*«Static element can hold dynamic elements/content... Think "wrapper"»*

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to try and help, https://codepen.io/jcollinz/pen/WOzmom is the pen. I tried your method, it didn't work for some reason, so I also tried my original JS script which did work and this is now not resetting it either. Could you see if you can spot whats going wrong, or perhaps its just a broken pen?

Comment: Actually this is the pen where the reset works, but the answers key only shows if its pressed before the reset. https://codepen.io/jcollinz/pen/NgywJx

Comment: I fixed your "answer key" button's function in [**this CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BZxXgj?editors=1010).

Comment: Awesome it seems to now allow for resets, but the only issue is [object HTMLDivElement] being displayed instead of the arrays actual value?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run 'clone()' with an optional [flag](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to ensure event handlers are copies/cloned as well. By default the handlers are NOT copied which is most likely why events aren't triggering after replace. Try the following:

```
$("#health").replaceWith(originalState.clone(true));
```

Otherwise you target an element that does not get removed and re-added to DOM and use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to target the respective sub elements of #health for click events:

```
$("#health").on("click", ".subitemClass", function(event) {});
```

Hopefully that helps!